# How to setup module install (sub-folder) paths from the *very beginning* (contrib, custom, features etc) - i.e. not move them after the install

Tags: 7, installation, uri

I've seen plenty of guides saying why it's a good thing to organise modules in different folders... (and I'd agree) e.g.:

- [Where to put custom modules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51072/where-to-put-custom-modules)
- https://drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes/modules-7
- http://befused.com/drupal/module-directory-structure (particularly like this guide, more folders and options to choose from)

...and how to move the modules to the new place(s) *after* installation

- [How to move installed modules from /sites/all/modules/* to /sites/all/contrib/modules/*](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17657/how-to-move-installed-modules-from-sites-all-modules-to-sites-all-contrib-mo)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654720/drupal-moving-module-folder
- [How to reorganize drupal sites/all/modules structure without symbolic links?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11505/how-to-reorganize-drupal-sites-all-modules-structure-without-symbolic-links?lq=1)

... but these haven't worked for me, perhaps I need to try again. My site broke, even after trying the registry rebuild and clear cache many times.

So my question is this: How can I run the installation of Drupal to set up the modules to be installed in different folders (e.g. like in examples http://befused.com/drupal/module-directory-structure )?

There doesn't seem to be anything out there if you want your module paths (sub-folders) structured in a certain way, right from the beginning. NOT after the fact.

I want the folders to be set up *in the first place*, right from the beginning. So example, whenever I use drush to download a contrib module, the module is placed in the contrib sub-folder: sites/all/modules/contrib for example.

Some other references:

- [Can Drupal be configured to find modules in other locations?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/can-drupal-be-configured-to-find-modules-in-other-locations) - this suggests Drupal can just discover the location, I'm not so keen on this, I'd rather Drupal always know where the modules are rather than having to discover where they are.
- [Is it possible to change the path of modules/themes installed using an installation profile?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28698/changing-the-path-of-modules-installed-using-an-installation-profile) - I just want to use the plain vanilla Drupal 7 core install. If I was going to use this option, what would be the minimum I would need to provide in a setup to have module sub-folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it seems like all you need to do is just create a folder called `contrib` in `/sites/all/modules`

when I issued drush dl views (at the docroot/install top level root of my site), drush put the views module in the contrib folder

as for features - you specify where you want the module to go when you (re)create the Feature (in the Feature section of the Drupal config)

as for custom - I'm hoping that Drupal will discover custom modules here - but is discovering, rather than a setting determining the path, a good thing?

Thought I'd still ask the question even after I'd found an answer, didn't want to waste the effort in making the question - hope someone else finds it useful.

Please provide your own answer or comment to enhance what I found.

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the registry using https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild? I usually build a site inside a custom installation profile and by using make files specify which folders different modules and themes should go into. I usually place custom modules under /profiles/MYPROFILE/modules/custom and contrib modules goes in /profiles/MYPROFILE/modules/contrib

Comment: +1 Great tips thanks Pontus Nilsson - I did try registry rebuild - I think I'd moved my modules into certain folders, it didn't work out (errors) then moved them back to the original place (still errors) and then tried registry_rebuild to sort it all out, but it wouldn't install. So now when I remember more of what happened, I think what would have worked would be to have installed registry_rebuild *before* attempting to move any modules to other folders.

Comment: That said I prefer the idea of having everything in the certain folders (contrib, custom etc) in the first place so your input on install profiles is something I'd want to explore.

Comment: Be aware that registry_rebuild isn't a module. It's a php script, see the documentation for more info.